# while loop doesn't stop the loop when the expression is false

Tags: python, while-loop

The code should stop when price_t <= k, but the programm runs till all elements are added together. thx!

**Test case**

```
7 50 \n
1 12 5 111 200 1000 10
```

```
first_multiple_input = input().rstrip().split()

n = int(first_multiple_input[0])

k = int(first_multiple_input[1])

prices = list(map(int, input().rstrip().split()))

prices=sorted(prices)
price_t=0
count=0
while price_t <= k:
    for i in range(len(prices)):
        price_t=price_t+prices[i]
        count+=1
    print(count )
```

Comment: You should terminate the for loop if the condition is breaking.

Comment: Your inner loop will run _in its entirety_ before the outer loop checks the condition again. Then, if the condition is not met, it will again run the inner loop _completely through_ before once again checking the condition

Comment: Possibly you wanted to iterate `for price in prices` and inside the loop accumulate each consecutive `price` only `if price_t <= k` and skip the rest of them once the threshold is reached.

Comment: @G.Anderson thank you very much! you answer is exactly what I need to know.

Answer (score 4):

If I rewrite your loop like this, is it clearer what's going on?

```py
while price_t <= k:
    for price in prices:
        price_t += price
```

The outer loop will only run when `price_t` is less than `k`.  But then inner loop will run *for every price in prices*.

what you want is probably:

```py
for price in prices:
    if price_t > k:
        break
    price_t += k
```

Comment: thank you , yes,  that is what i mean